# Android opengl blending

Tags: android, blend, opengl

Есть *png* текстура c альфа-каналом. Загружаю ее, используя BitmapFactory. На эмуляторе смешивание отрабатывает отлично. Виден задний фон, где альфа равна 0. Вот формула:

`glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Тестировал на реальных устройствах - **Samsung Galaxy Young и Texet TM9750**.
В результате вместо заднего фона получаются белые пиксели.
Всем спасибо )